# Text location in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, text, formatting, jtextarea

I have the following question: can I align one part of text along the right edge and another along the left if this text is in one line?

Now I'll try to explain clearer. I have this window:

[image]

Can I align time of receiving by the right edge? Now I separate time by usual tabulation. Here's the code of the method:

```
frame.getSubscribe().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        sTopic = frame.getTopicValue();
        try {
            if (mqttClient.isConnected()) {
                mqttClient.subscribe(sTopic);
                MqttCallback callback = new MqttCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
                        Date date = new Date();
                        String sDate = date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes()+":"+date.getSeconds();
                        frame.getTextArea().append(String.valueOf(mqttMessage)+"\t\t"+sDate+'\n');
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

                    }
                };
                mqttClient.setCallback(callback);
            }
        } catch (MqttException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Subscribed");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you ? Probably, should you .... hmmm ... I'd probably use a `JEditorPane` with a `HTMLEditor` and then just use a `<table>` OR just use a `JTable` and be done with it

Comment: This might be better suited to another Swing component, such as a `JTable`. But if a `JTextArea` will do, then use a fixed width font to align characters to specific places.